# How to Join 2 Publishers having different Objects using a key in Reactor (similar to an SQL join)

Tags: project-reactor

Given

- 2 Publishers each with its own Object
- Publishers would share a key object
- Each publisher would be already sorted by that key.

How to join these 2 Publishers similar to an SQL JOIN

- inner join
- left join / right join

Example:

```
Flux<Client> 
Flux<Invoice>
```

- each having a field clientId

the output would be a

```
Flux<Tuple3<ClientId, Client, Invoice>>
or 
Flux<ClientInvoice>
```

Comment: Does each input flow has a single entry for each client id (i.e. there is only one Invoice for a given client id) ? If there's a 1/1 match, a simple zip could do. Otherwise, I think the best bet is to reduce/collect one of both  (preferably the one with less entry, or the one that answer more quickly) in a cached `Mono<Map<ClientId, T>>` . With that, you can do something like (very approximate snippet) : `flatMap(other -> cache.map(cache -> cache.get(other.getClientId()).map(cached -> new ClientInvoice(other, cached);`. Of course, this works only if one of your datasource is not too big.

Comment: No, it is not a 1/1 match, and even though you could think of begin 1/1 if an Invoice is missing a zip again will not work.
No, I don't want to collect everything in memory, this defies the purpose

Comment: It is an interesting problem. I do not think there's a specialized operator for this. However, It should be possible to create one manually (using subscribers/processors underneath). To orient answers, I think you could add the streaming requirement to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible algorithms can be applied here: algorithm with O(n^2) complexity and algorithm with O(n) complexity. I suppose you are not interested in O(n^2), so I will provide an example of an algorithm with O(n) complexity.

To reduce algorithmic complexity, we need to group all invoices by clientId in some hash-based data structure like HashMap:

```java
Mono<Map<Integer, Collection<Invoice>>> clientIdToInvoice = getInvoices()
    .collectMultimap(Invoice::getClientId, Function.identity(), HashMap::new) // this allows us to get all invoices for specific clientId with O(1) complexity
    .cache(); // this caches the Map to reuse it without recalculation.
```

Then we can iterate over clients and get all invoices for each client from the map we defined on previous step:

```java
getClients()
    .flatMap(client -> clientIdToInvoice
        .flatMapMany(mapping -> Flux.fromIterable(mapping.getOrDefault(client.getId(), List.of())))
        .map(invoice -> new ClientToInvoice(client, invoice))
    )
    .doOnNext(System.out::println) // your logic here
    .subscribe();
```

This method involves iterating through both the `invoices` and `clients` flux only once. However, it's important to consider that if your client/invoice collection are large, it could impact memory usage. In such cases, it may be more efficient to move this logic to the database.

**Update 1**

If you don't want to load all elements into the memory and you have both streams already sorted by matching key, then you can try to achieve what you want with a custom `Subscriber` that requests elements from stream 1-by-1 or batching (which is preferable, because 1-by-1 can reduce performance). I provide the simplest example to share the idea. Then you can improve it with corner cases.

Custom subscriber example

```java
class InvoiceCollectingSubscriber implements Subscriber<Invoice> {
    private Client client;
    private Subscription subscription;
    private CompletableFuture<ClientToInvoice> response;

    public Mono<ClientToInvoice> nextClient(Client client) {
        this.client = client;
        this.response = new CompletableFuture<>();
        this.subscription.request(1); // it requests 1 element from invoice flux, you can rewrite logic to batches, etc.
        return Mono.fromFuture(this.response);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {
        this.subscription = s;
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(Invoice invoice) {
        this.response.complete(new ClientToInvoice(this.client, invoice));
        // here you can also do this.subscription.request(n) if you expect more than 1 invoice per user
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable t) {
        // todo
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete() {
        // todo
    }
}
```

main code example

```java
var subscriber = new InvoiceCollectingSubscriber();
getInvoices()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel())
    .subscribe(subscriber);
getClients()
    .concatMap(subscriber::nextClient) // concat map allows processing elements in order and sequentially
    .take(4) // you can replace with any other strategy that decides when to stop (by time, size, etc)
    .doOnNext(it -> System.out.println("next: " + it))
    .doOnComplete(() -> System.out.println("done"))
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel())
    .subscribe();
```

As I said, this is the simplest example just to share ideas. It works only with 1-1 mapping.

These is example arguments:

```java
Flux<Client> getClients() {
    return Flux.just(
        new Client(1),
        new Client(2),
        new Client(3),
        new Client(4)
    );
}

Flux<Invoice> getInvoices() {
    return Flux.just(
        new Invoice(501, 1),
        new Invoice(502, 2),
        new Invoice(503, 3),
        new Invoice(504, 4)
    );
}
```

Output:

```
next: ClientToInvoice{client=1, invoice=501}
next: ClientToInvoice{client=2, invoice=502}
next: ClientToInvoice{client=3, invoice=503}
next: ClientToInvoice{client=4, invoice=504}
done
```

Comment: The idea of collecting in memory one of the sides was the first I jumped on BUT
I don't want to collect in memory (the stream could be too large), using the idea that each stream is already sorted by the key the solution would be something similar to merge-sort

Comment: @AdrianI got it, I've updated my answer with another option that should be suitable for your case

Comment: @AdrianI Did it assist you in completing your task?